# HTML dropdown & php dynamic creation

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble creating option and posting them along with the form its a part of.

Here's what I currently have. The db connector is already working.

```
 <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_5"       name="account">
 <?php
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
 $bid =$row[0];
$account = $row[1];
echo '<option value="'.$bid.'>"'.$account.'"</option>"';

}

?>
</select>
```

It will not post to:

```
   function calculateBilling(){ 

        $date = date('mdY');
        $bid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bid']);
        $account = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['account']);
        $timein = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timein']);
        $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
        $hrs2calc1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hrly']);
        $hrs2calc2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rhrly']);


        $query = 'SELECT bid, account, hrly, rhrly, bal FROM billing WHERE bid="'.$bid.'"';

        echo $query;
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                $accounttobebilled = $row[1];
                $first = $row[2];
                $second = $row[3];
                $curbal = $row[4];
            }

            $sub1 = $hrly * $hrs2calc1;
            $sub2 = $rhrly * $hrs2calc2;
            $subtotal = $sub1 + $sub2;

            $total = $curbal + $subtotal;

            mysql_query("UPDATE billing SET bal = '" . $total . "' WHERE bid ='" . $bid . "'");


        // Update Billing Log for this customer

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO billingLog (bid, date, hrsOnsite, hrsRemote, timein, descript, total) VALUES ('$bid', '$date', '$hrs2calc1', '$hrs2calc2', '$timein', '$desc', '$subtotal')");

   }
```

My problem is the billing id (bid) is not posting along with the form it is wrapped in. If I echo $bid on the html page before I post it, it pulls fine. It just doesn't post to the function above. bid is an integer.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide the outputted HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are wacky:

```
echo '<option value="'.$bid.'>"'.$account.'"</option>"';
```

would output: `<option value="123>"My Account Name"</option>"`

Try this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$bid.'">'.$account.'</option>';
```

That should output: `<option value="123">My Account Name</option>`

Comment: I always screw those up.. It won't post to my php.. Look above!! thank you

Comment: Trust me :) Based on your code, this is why it's not working.

Comment: No.. It's not posting to the function above. I fixed the quotes though.

Comment: The only thing I see based off of your updated code is that you're running your SQL query looking at `$bid` when the `<select name="account">` and should probably be `<select name="bid">`

Answer (score 0):

My name on the item wasn't bid. Fixed!